# Why is my surfaceCreated never called

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

I'm a noobie in android dev and I'm having a issue. I'm trying to make a simple game using SurfaceView. But surfaceCreated is never called when I'm launching the app.

I'm using [his](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24889558/9108386) answer to use less ram with the background
**Here is where the setcontentView is placed:**

```
call_surfaceView = new class_surfaceView(cMainActivity);
// Setup your SurfaceView
SurfaceView surfaceView = call_surfaceView;  // use any SurfaceView you want
surfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
surfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

// Setup your ImageView
ImageView bgImagePanel = new ImageView(cMainActivity);
bgImagePanel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background); // use any Bitmap or BitmapDrawable you want

// Use a RelativeLayout to overlap both SurfaceView and ImageView
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams fillParentLayout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
RelativeLayout rootPanel = new RelativeLayout(cMainActivity);
rootPanel.setLayoutParams(fillParentLayout);
rootPanel.addView(bgImagePanel, fillParentLayout);
rootPanel.addView(surfaceView, fillParentLayout);
setContentView(rootPanel);
```

and here is **my surfaceView code:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class class_surfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    Thread t;
    Canvas c;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    Bitmap ghost;
    Bitmap lifebar;
    Bitmap player;
    Bitmap sol;
    Bitmap tombe;

    public class_surfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        holder = getHolder();
        Log.d("Essai", "Class_surfaceView");
    }
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.d("Essai", "surfaceCreated");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               lauch_game();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    }

    public void lauch_game() {
        ghost = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ghost);
        c = holder.lockCanvas();
        if(c != null){
            c.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
            c.drawBitmap(ghost,0,0,null);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        } else {
            Log.d("DEBUG","c is null");
        }
        Log.d("Essai", "Essais de dessin");
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping !

Comment: Just saying, the function is spelled "lauch_game" instead of "launch_game"

Comment: Thanks I'll correct it !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your class_surfaceView constructor after holder = getHolder(), you must call holder.addCallback(this) to register the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use @Override above method

Comment: He wouldn't need to; it's (I assume) not part of the parent class.