# display transparent view over existing views

Tags: android

In Android 2.2, I want to display a few sprites and clickable animations over an existing view.  I just discovered that [SurfaceView cannot be transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391089/how-to-make-surfaceview-transparent/5396110#5396110)

I tried [overriding `dispatchDraw()` of a `LinearLayout`](http://www.androidapps.org/tag/mapview) but that doesn't seem to be callable via a `Runnable` `Thread`.

I also tried to extend `Canvas` directly, but that quickly turned into a mess when trying to place it in my XML layout.

Do I have to use [GLSurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TranslucentGLSurfaceViewActivity.html) to have a drawing view whose background is transparent?

Optimally, I'd like to just have a `Canvas` on which I can draw `Bitmap` at various coordinates, instead of dealing with the details of GL (unless GL is the only way I can do transparency).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly Rabbit.  Just use Views and move them around wherever you want within a FrameLayout.  SurfaceView is not designed for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try [Switching from Canvas to OpenGL](http://obviam.net/index.php/opengl-es-with-android-switching-from-canvas-to-opengl/) and toss in parts of [TranslucentGLSurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TranslucentGLSurfaceViewActivity.html).

I'm still open to selecting an answer that doesn't require OpenGL, just for the sake of it solving my original question.

Comment: OpenGL ES will work really great in HoneyComb (3.0+). I'm not sure if Google will backport OpenGl ES for versions < 3.0. Translucence is attainable tho, but is quite hacky.