# How to add view as background to the surfaceView?

Tags: android, view, background, surfaceview

Hi I am currently working on Game which contains VIEW of visualization of audio frequency effect in background of surfaceView.

**`The surfaceView contains actual game play.`**

I posting some code snippets :-

**`main.xml`**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#000" >

    <co.ardor.visualizer.VisualizerView
        android:id="@+id/visualizerView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </co.ardor.visualizer.VisualizerView>
</FrameLayout>
```

**`Visualizer view`** are created as follows -

```
public class VisualizerView extends View
{
  private static final String TAG = "VisualizerView";

  private byte[] mBytes;
  private byte[] mFFTBytes;
  private Rect mRect = new Rect();
  private Visualizer mVisualizer;
  private Set<Renderer> mRenderers; // type of Renderer class

  private Paint mFlashPaint = new Paint(); // for flash paint
  private Paint mFadePaint = new Paint(); // for fade paint

  public VisualizerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
  {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
 }

  public VisualizerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
 {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
 }

  public VisualizerView(Context context)
  {
   this(context, null, 0);
  } 

  // Some code regarding to the audio visualization..
}
```

My VisualizerView running well so how I can add this as background to SurfaceView (Actual running Game).I am stuck on the problem that **`"How to add VIEW as background of surfaceView?"`** Or any another better solution for that.. 
Thx in advance..

Comment: Views can not be added as background. You have to set it as content view of your Activity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possibility you could have a look at is to retrieve the `View's` drawing cache `Bitmap` and add the `Bitmap` to the `SurfaceView`, drawn behind your game contents.

Retrieve the `Bitmap`:

```
myVisualizerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
mVisualizerBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myVisualizerView.getDrawingCache());
myVisualizerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Draw the `Bitmap` in SurfaceView's `onDraw(...)`:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(mVisualizerBitmap, //other params);
```

I'm not sure this is a great idea in terms of performance if you have to retrieve the bitmap every frame of your game but it could be worth exploring.

Comment: Thanks Gunnar for replying but this is not good for realtime sound visualisation... But I really impressed from your idea.

Comment: Have you had a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391089/how-to-make-surfaceview-transparent - ?

Comment: I got solution from this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/15873927/2123594. But your suggested answer is also well.  Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

try to add them using LinearLayout,
and make them on top of each other using:

```
android:layout_alignLeft="..."
android:layout_alignTop="..."
```