# Android SurfaceView causing screen flicker

Tags: android, android-fragments, surfaceview, android-mediaplayer, flicker

I'm working on a multimedia video processing application for Android, and I've run into a bit of a problem. I'm using the `FragmentPagerAdapter` class with a number of different fragments inside for various steps of video processing.

My first `Fragment` contains a `SurfaceView` and a `MediaPlayer` that feeds it, along with various playback controls. My problem happens when I swipe from fragment 1 (with the SurfaceView) to fragment 2 (empty at the moment). If I haven't yet called `start()`, nothing unusual happens, and I'm able to swipe between fragments normally. Once I call `start()` however, the entire screen starts flashing on and off when I swipe to the next `Fragment`, even if I've put the `MediaPlayer` in the idle state and it's not feeding frames to `SurfaceView`. The only thing that stops this is destroying the surface along with the containing view by swiping to the third `Fragment` so the `FragmentPagerAdapter` destroys `Fragment` one, or exiting the application via the home or back button so the view is destroyed.

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening, other than that perhaps the `SurfaceView` rendering thread is somehow interfering with the main UI thread. Nothing unusual appears on LogCat, either, so I'm a bit stuck. I'm running a Galaxy Nexus with android 4.1 as my test hardware.

Any help would be appreciated!

JT

**UPDATE:** I've managed to find a workaround for now by overriding the `setPrimaryItem()` method in the `FragmentPagerAdapter` to call a method that removes the `SurfaceView` from the hierarchy (using `removeView()` on its `LinearLayout` container) when the video player `Fragment` ceases to be displayed, and then reinstates the `SurfaceView` when it's active again. There's still a bit of a blink when this happens, unfortunately, so if anyone has additional thoughts, I'd be grateful!

Comment: check this answer. your problem is similar to this: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772862/surfaceview-flashes-black-on-load)

Answer (score 4):

From the [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/11/android-40-graphics-and-animations.html)

> This widget[SurfaceView] works by creating a new window placed behind your application’s window. It then punches a hole through your application’s window to reveal the new window.
>
> Because a SurfaceView’s content does not live in the application’s window, it cannot be transformed (moved, scaled, rotated) efficiently. This makes it difficult to use a SurfaceView inside a ListView or a ScrollView.

The Solution is to use a TextureView if you're building for 4.0 or above. If youre interested in using a TextureView to display video [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736517/playing-video-on-textureview) might be helpful

Comment: Awesome answer.... I spent my 1 week to solve this problem ..... finally removed SurfaceView/VideoView and used TextureView.