# Single black flicker when adding GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I use a GLSurfaceView inside a CompoundView to implement a fancy navigation. Currently the GLSurfaceView is created when a subsection is selected, not right at the start.

My problem is that the screen flickers for an instant when the GLSurfaceView is created for the first time. It doesn't flicker when a different subsection is selected; in that case the current GLSurfaceView discarded and another one created.

This, of course, is very irritating, especially because it flickers black on a very light theme. I guess in most cases it wouldn't matter, because GLSurfaceViews are usually full screen and quite long lived, but in this case it's a traditional android app that opens and closes activities all the time.

Is there a way to circumvent this? Like pre-initializing OpenGl when the activity is created (i assume the flicker wouldn't be as annoying there)?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Looks like this solves it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772862/surfaceview-flashes-black-on-load/12636285#12636285

Comment: Sorry björn, I don't remember how I solved this.