# Navigationdrawer under MapFragment and CameraView (Surfaceview)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, camera, surfaceview

I have a bug with the google maps fragment. The fragment is placed inside my activity and when i open the navigation drawer it is displayed behind the maps fragment. that's strange because the navigation drawer is on top of the fragment in the layout.

Same problem with the CameraView.

problem detected on android 2.3 and some

Answer (score 7):

Reason: The CameraView and the MapFragment are SurfaceViews.

Solution:

```
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/palce_map_here"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/bugfixview"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

draw a transparent view on top of the surface view.

Comment: This works perfectly! I can't quite figure out why, but it does. This helped me a lot, thank you!