# IMA SDK black screen before load ads in Android

Tags: android, surfaceview, imasdk

I am using IMA SDK in android after ad request it is showing a black screen for a few seconds then load ads immediately.
After debugging the code and inspecting element I found after requesting ads the ima SDK loads a surface view over a player with that black screen.

I want if ad load then only show surface view not before they load surface view.

[image]

Comment: Hello, I got same issue when loading ads *.mp4 file by using PlayerView in ExoPlayer. Did you find solution?

Comment: Your issue looks duplicate like [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772862/surfaceview-flashes-black-on-load?rq=1)