# Drawing a Large Bitmap Background to SurfaceView Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, surfaceview

I am trying to find the best way (preformance-wise) to draw a large `Bitmap` to a `SurfaceView` in Android as a stationary background image. I am currently just using the `Canvas.drawBitmap()` method but it brings my FPS down by a lot. What are some ways that I can speed this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use an opaque image and set the Xfermode on the Paint to either null or PorterDuff.Mode.SRC. This will disable blending which can be expensive. Also make sure your image is not stretched (no scaling) and that it's in the same format as the surfaceview's surface.

Comment: Thanks I used your suggestions and they gave me roughly 5-10 more FPS. It runs smoothly for about 10 seconds and then experiences a lag that brings the game down A LOT! down to about 10 FPS. Any ideas? When I am not drawing the background image this lag doesn't occur.

Answer (score 0):

If your background is going to be static, then you could try making the background of your layout the background image. Then put the surfaceView background as transparent:

[how to make surfaceview transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391089/how-to-make-surfaceview-transparent)