# How to covert imageview into different shape?

Tags: android, imageview, android-shapedrawable

Actually I wanna convert the image into the mentioned shape in picture . I've tried a lot of similar questions in `SO` but none of them were helpful. You may advise to use drawable in foreground of `imageView` but I've gotta set the foreground programmatically which is valid only api>23 . Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

You can see in image that there's background of image . I wanna convert the image into that shape programmatically.

Even I tried to use `Gradient Drawable` but it was futile

Code:

```
GradientDrawable gradientDrawable= new GradientDrawable();
        float[] radii = new float[8];
        radii[0] = 15; // Goes clockwise, so this is the top left corner start position.
        radii[1] = 15; // top left end position.
        radii[2] = 15;
        radii[3] = 15;
        radii[4]=0;
        radii[5]=0;
        radii[6] = 15;
        radii[7] = 15;
        gradientDrawable.setCornerRadii(radii);
        holder.img.setBackgroundDrawable(gradientDrawable);
```

[image]

Comment: `setBackgroundDrawable` is deprecated. Instead use `setBackground`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the `onDraw` method of your imageView class by applying a clipPath:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    float[] radii = new float[8];
    radii[0] = radius; // Goes clockwise, so this is the top left corner start position.
    radii[1] = radius; // top left end position.
    radii[2] = radius;
    radii[3] = radius;
    // Skipping 4 and 5 because thats the bottom right corner.
    radii[6] = radius;
    radii[7] = radius;
    Path clipPath = new Path();
    clipPath.addRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight()), radii, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.clipPath(clipPath);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

refs:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#ondraw

Comment: Sir thanks a lot for your answer but it's showing can't resolve constructor for this line **clipPath.addRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), radii, Path.Direction.CW);**

Comment: @user8027365 I forgot a bracket to close off the `RectF`, fixed it in the example.

Comment: Hmm, and you added it to your ImageView extended class? Or are you creating your ImageView in a different way?

Comment: it's not changing anything

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a drawable image then you can set a different radius for a different corner like

```
<corners
    android:topRightRadius="15dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"/>
```

Apart from that, you can use 
[GradientDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable) to create a background image and use `setCornerRadii` for variable corner radius.

Example for GradientDrawable

```
GradientDrawable gradientDrawable= new GradientDrawable();
gradientDrawable.setCornerRadii(15,15,15,15,15,15,0,0);
```

> **void setCornerRadii (float[] radii)**
>
> Specifies radii for each of the 4 corners. For each corner, the array
>   contains 2 values, [X_radius, Y_radius]. The corners are ordered
>   top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left. This property is
>   honored only when the shape is of type RECTANGLE.

for setting color use `gradientDrawable.setColor(YOUR_COLOR)` method and you can use multiple color there for gradient look.

Here (15,15,15,15,15,15,0,0) suggest X radius and Y radius for all 4 corner starting from top left.

Comment: could you please elaborate how to use  **Gradient Drawable** for my case @Kunu

Comment: should i set this gradient as my background ? @Kunu

Comment: If you use single color and it will be same as normal background.

Comment: It's not chaning anything sir

Comment: Can you update your question with your updated code?

Comment: `setBackgroundDrawable` is deprecated. Instead use `setBackground`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved my problem by taking reference from [from this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13640040/8027365) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50117588/8027365)

Finally the ImageView Class looks like:

```
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

private Path mMaskPath;
private Paint mMaskPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
private int mCornerRadius = 10;

public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    init();
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    super(context, attributeSet);

    init();
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    init();
}

private void init() {
    ViewCompat.setLayerType(this, ViewCompat.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    mMaskPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
}


public void setCornerRadius(int cornerRadius) {
    mCornerRadius = cornerRadius;
    generateMaskPath(getWidth(), getHeight());
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldW, oldH);

    if (w != oldW || h != oldH) {
        generateMaskPath(w, h);
    }
}

private void generateMaskPath(int w, int h) {
    mMaskPath = new Path();
    float[] radii = new float[8];
    radii[0] = 20; // Goes clockwise, so this is the top left corner start position.
    radii[1] = 20; // top left end position.
    radii[2] = 20;
    radii[3] = 20;
    // Skipping 4 and 5 because thats the bottom right corner.
    radii[6] = 20;
    radii[7] = 20;
    mMaskPath.addRoundRect(new RectF(0,0,w,h), radii, Path.Direction.CW);
    mMaskPath.setFillType(Path.FillType.INVERSE_WINDING);
}

@SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if(canvas.isOpaque()) { // If canvas is opaque, make it transparent
        canvas.saveLayerAlpha(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), 255, Canvas.HAS_ALPHA_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG);
    }

    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if(mMaskPath != null) {
        canvas.drawPath(mMaskPath, mMaskPaint);
    }
}
 }
```