# Android transparent SurfaceView clears to black

Tags: android, canvas, transparency

I want to put a transparent SurfaceView on top of an ImageView. I have the following in the SurfaceView subclass constructor

```
setZOrderOnTop(true);    // necessary
SurfaceHolder h = getHolder();
h.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
```

I also have this in the beginning of the onDraw() function

```
canvas.drawColor( 0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR );
```

Yet, all I get is a black background which blocks the image.

Any ideas?

PS, I also tried this instead of drawColor(), but to no avail

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.CLEAR));
canvas.drawPaint(paint);
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC));
```

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) which recreates your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SurfaceViews cannot be transparent in this way. Try a SurfaceTexture if you're on API 11 or above, or draw into a regular View in other cases.

A SurfaceView is a special case that coordinates surface compositing in a special way optimized for performance. You can draw content on top of a SurfaceView in your view hierarchy if configured for it, but you cannot blend a SurfaceView's content with content behind it.

Comment: First, thanks for the reply. From this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391089/how-to-make-surfaceview-transparent I thought that it's possible. Do you have an example of how to use a simple view, to mimic SurfaceView functionality?

Comment: What is it that you're actually trying to do? Why do you have a SurfaceView on top of an ImageView? What's the use case?

Comment: I want to draw some shapes over an image. I changed the code to subclass View, and used invalidate() after to force draw. Seems to be working fine. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, if that's all you want to do, that's the way to go. SurfaceView pulls in a lot of other things to worry about that you don't need for such a simple case. Glad you got it!

Comment: This is my first post, so I can't vote you up. Hopefully others will do, so others won't get confused on this subject.

Answer (score 2):

I know, that this post is a year old, but you set the color to 0, which stands for black. Use

```
canvas.drawColor( Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR );
```

to make it transparent.

Comment: This works if it is a View, but as @adamp says above, SurfaceView involves a whole different method of doing things. Simply setting the background to transparent won't work. What you can do is `surfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true)`, which will allow the stuff behind the SurfaceView to show through. This can create other problems, however, like if you have a Nav Drawer; the SurfaceView will also be on top of the drawer.