# Make a SurfaceView transparent without setZOrderOnTop(true)

Tags: java, android, layout

I have a RelativeLayout containing a custom SurfaceView and other elements that must be drawn over the SurfaceView. I also need the SurfaceView to be transparent.
I tried this answer: [how to make surfaceview transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391089/how-to-make-surfaceview-transparent). But with the setZOrderOnTop(true) the other elements over the SurfaceView in the RelativeLayout are shown above the Surface (and partially hidden if the surface have something paint).

How can I solve this problem? thanks

Comment: What you need? do you want to add Background to your surfaceview and also add another views on top of your surfaceview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the holder pixel format to RGBA_8888,

```
sv.setZOrderOnTop(true);    //very much necessary
```

`getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);`

Comment: Didn't work for me, at least for min3d lib. Any requirements on the OpenGL version for that?

Answer (score 0):

I had success with the `setZOrderMediaOverlay(true)` instead of `setZOrderOnTop(true)`. It allows for both Views below and above the OpenGL SurfaceView.

Here it is in context:

```
GLSurfaceView glview = (GLSurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surface);
glview.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
glview.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
glview.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
glview.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
```

Comment: can you show me the piece of code for the same, i am using it as:

                setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
  SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
  holder.addCallback(this);
  holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
But it didn't show any thing,infact it goes beyond the other view.
when activity is starting i can see that work i done on surface, but suddenly over come by my view.

Comment: I added some context for that function call. It is in the onCreate of the activity that contains the surface.

Comment: thanx for the help, let me try it.