# Custom SurfaceView Make transparent in Android

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have made a custom MySurfaceView by extending calss SurfaceView itd working fine as per my need but problem is black background I want it transparent.

My code like this.

```
lay = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.timer_lay);

    MySurfaceView msv = new MySurfaceView(this);
    lay.addView(tv);
```

and I want that the the background color of `timer_lay` should become background color of `MySurfaceView` than I can I do this in `onDraw` method.

Comment: try this msv.setZOrderOnTop(true);    // necessary
msv = msv.getHolder();
msv.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

Comment: The above, taken from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391089/how-to-make-surfaceview-transparent . please provide links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes its worked for me got a solution, Thanks to g00dy

```
MySurfaceView msv = (MySurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.custom_view);
msv.setZOrderOnTop(true);   
sHolder = msv.getHolder();
sHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MySurfaceView msv = new MySurfaceView(this);
msv.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```