# How to make surfaceview transparent background?

Tags: android, surfaceview, transparent

I want to make my `GLSurfaceView` transparent. I tried:

```
setZOrderOnTop(true);
setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
mRenderer = new CurlRenderer(this);
getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

It works, but I need to display another view above `GLSurfaceView`.

Is it possible to not use `setZOrderOnTop(true)`?

Answer (score 2):

No. `setZOrderOnTop` **must** be called to have a transparent `SurfaceView` background. You cannot have anything above a transparent `SurfaceView`.

Comment: +1 for something i didnt know. Do you have any reliable source? (i trust you, but just for knowing the source)

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/jYjvm7ItpXQ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391089/how-to-make-surfaceview-transparent

Comment: This is so frustrating.