# Android best view for video streaming

Tags: android, ffmpeg, java-native-interface, streaming, native

I'm working on media streaming application that get video frames from camera and encode it using FFMPEG native c library and send it on socket and on the other hand receive and decode it then show it.

now my question is which View is better for showing video frames and why ?

SurfaceView or TextureView or GLSurfaceView or ANativeWindow

Comment: Have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21305651/295004

Comment: GLSurfaceView definitely, and as for video rendering, look into a custom YUV fragment shader.