# android grafika ContinuousCapture activity issues

Tags: java, android, grafika

I'm using android grafika for video recording and I'll change all things that I want.
Everything works perfectly.

There are only 2 problems:

1. If I save video after 7 seconds like 2 seconds or below 7 seconds then it saves a 7 second video.
2. If I take a video 15 seconds or more then it takes the **last** 7 seconds of video.

I want to solution :

1. if I save after 7 second video like for a 2 second then save the video for 2 second
2. I want to save **first** 7 seconds of video

This Github link which I follow : **[Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika)**

How to solve these 2 problems?

## Note:

If you have Orientation issue in `portrait` mode then follow below link:

**[Orientation Issue while video recording in Portrait Mode android grafika](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53533890/orientation-issue-while-video-recording-in-portrait-mode-android-grafika/53568383#53568383)**

Comment: Hi Ali, have my number: +989155577437

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: But I haven't yours