# Orientation Issue while video recording in Portrait Mode android grafika

Tags: android, orientation, android-mediacodec, grafika

I set the device Orientation `Landscape` mode then it saves the video perfectly. 
if I capture a video with both sides.

But I set the device orientation `Portrait` Mode this work weird.

For Example:

Below Screenshot while i Recording video :

[image]

But when i save the video and see in MXPlayer then it's look like this:

[image]

I use below code :

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

        if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0) {
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            //  layout.setAspectRatio((double) cameraPreviewSize.height / cameraPreviewSize.width);
        } else if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
            // layout.setAspectRatio((double) cameraPreviewSize.height / cameraPreviewSize.width);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
        } else {
            // Set the preview aspect ratio.
            //layout.setAspectRatio((double) cameraPreviewSize.width / cameraPreviewSize.height);
        }
```

## UPDATE:

Also i try to add **[setOrientationHint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer#setOrientationHint(int))** where i start the **`MediaMuxer`**

Comment: @fadden do you have any idea why this work weird in `portrait` mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after 2 day i solve my problem.

## This Solution for `Grafika`  `ContinuousCaptureActivity.java`

In **`drawFrame()`** Method i'll change some code for `portrait`.

I add below 2 line in `drawFrame` method:

```
Matrix.rotateM(mTmpMatrix, 0, 270, 0, 0, 1);
Matrix.translateM(mTmpMatrix, 0, -1, 0, 0);
```

In `drawFrame` Method 2 type to set the `glViewport`

- First For **Fill the `SurfaceView` with it**. (it means this orientation change while user recording a video)
- Second For **Send it to the video encoder**. (it means this orientation change after save the video)

**So i'll be change in 2nd opetion**

Please find full code at below :

```
 // Send it to the video encoder.
        if (!mFileSaveInProgress) {
            mEncoderSurface.makeCurrent();
            if (!AppSetting.getValue(activity, Config.ORIENTATION, "").equalsIgnoreCase("Select")) {
                if (AppSetting.getValue(activity, Config.ORIENTATION, "").equalsIgnoreCase("Portrait")) {
                    Matrix.rotateM(mTmpMatrix, 0, 270, 0, 0, 1);
                    Matrix.translateM(mTmpMatrix, 0, -1, 0, 0);
                }
            }
            GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT);
            mFullFrameBlit.drawFrame(mTextureId, mTmpMatrix);
            //drawExtra(mFrameNum, VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT);
            mCircEncoder.frameAvailableSoon();
            mEncoderSurface.setPresentationTime(mCameraTexture.getTimestamp());
            mEncoderSurface.swapBuffers();
```