# Add view on top of transparent SurfaceView?

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7061396/2474498) describes how to make a `SurfaceView` with a transparent background.

However it requires `setZOrderOnTop(true)` to be called on the `SurfaceView`, which unsurprisingly puts the `SurfaceView` on top of the other views.

This isn't exactly what I want. Given `View`s `A`, `C`, and `SurfaceView` `B` I would like to order the views as `A` behind `B` behind `C`.

If `B` weren't a `SurfaceView` with a transparent background this would simply be:

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <ViewA>
  <ViewB>
  <ViewC>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is it possible to achieve this when `B` is a `SurfaceView` with a transparent background?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are four possible layers with the current SurfaceView API.  From top to bottom:

- setZOrderOnTop
- (Views)
- setZOrderMediaOverlay
- default

The SurfaceView surface, and the surface with all of the Views, are composited by the system compositor.  You cannot Z-order sandwich a SurfaceView surface between two Views.  (If you want the full details, read [this article](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html).  See also the multi-surface test activity in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika), which software-renders to three overlapping transparent SurfaceViews.)

What you may want to do is use a [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) (API 14+), which has many of the same properties but interacts fully with Views.  If you were using Canvas to draw on your SurfaceView, you may be able to use a custom View, which has the added advantage of [hardware accelerated](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) rendering.

Comment: Thank you. Which do you think will have better performance for a paint-esque overlay, TextureView with Canvas and a rendering Thread or a custom View?

Comment: Rendering with Canvas on a surface is never hardware accelerated.  That applies to both SurfaceView and TextureView.  You'll get better performance with a custom View.  There are some limitations to the hardware-accelerated renderer, so do look over the lists of supported features on the hardware acceleration page linked in the answer.