# Android - Make camera preview semi-transparent

Tags: android, android-camera, transparency, surfaceview

I want to make my camera preview see through. I saw this following post:

[how to make surfaceview transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391089/how-to-make-surfaceview-transparent)

About making a surface view transparent but the problem is that I am extending surface view for more control over the camera and they say that extending the surface view will make this solution invalid and don't explain why/propose another solution.

What can I do to achieve this?

EDIT:

Yes, I have tried what is in the Linked Post.

THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE

```
             TOP
=================================

 SEMI-TRANSPARENT CAMERA PREVIEW
         [FULLSCREEN]
=================================

        IMAGES AND TEXT
=================================

           BOTTOM
```

Comment: Have you *tried* this *at all*?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what it is you're trying to do?  i.e. the order of layers, which are transparent, what is on each, etc.  Remember that SurfaceView has two parts (the Surface and the View) that are composited independently.

Comment: @323go Yes of I have tried it. fadden I want to have a surface view which is a camera preview that will be semi transparent and will fill the entire screen. Behind it you will be able to see text and images and stuff like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place another view over your Preview view and make that view semi-transparent. To make  view semi-transparent you have to give alpha value with color to the background
ex:

```
 <View 
      android:background=#88000000/>
```

Comment: I do not believe you understand what I am asking thoroughly so I have edited the question to make it clearer.