# How to create circle camera preview in Android?

Tags: android, canvas, camera, rectangles

In my app, I need to create a **circle camera preview** from `Service`. I create a **CameraPreview** class, which extends `SurfaceView`. In my service, I added **CameraPreview** object to `WindowManager`.

For getting circle, I override methods `draw` and `dispatchDraw` of SurfaceView:

```
    Path circ = new Path();
    circ.addCircle(canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getWidth() / 2, Path.Direction.CW);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    canvas.drawPath(circ, paint);

    this.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

Here are my results for 3 different tests:

1. If I create **CameraPreview** object in `Service`, I get rectangle.
2. If I create **CameraPreview** object in an `Activity` with **no-transparent** theme, I get circle.
3. If I create **CameraPreview** object in an `Activity` with `Theme.Translucent`, I get rectangle.

Please tell me why I got these results. How does the theme of `Activity` affect to `Canvas`?

Comment: Maybe try setting the SurfaceHolder format?  Like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391089/how-to-make-surfaceview-transparent)

Comment: @Buddy It doesn't help.