# Draw circle in layout

Tags: android, canvas

I want to have a background in my activity which represents the building. I want to draw a small dot/circle which represents actual position of the phone, but I can't figure out, how should be done. I read some topics, write this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SurfaceView surface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
        surface.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                // Do some drawing when surface is ready
                Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                canvas.drawRect(50, 50, 200, 200, paint);
                //canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            }
        });
    }

}
```

and this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/map"
    >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

But it doesn't work, when it runs, the map disappear, and only the red rectangle is visible.

My question is: what should be done to leave the background map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make the SurfaceView transparent in order to do that. Check out this answer here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7061396/5512274

All the best :)