# How to put an image view over gpu image view while setZOrderOnTop is on?

Tags: android, glsurfaceview, android-gpuimageview

I'm using gpu image view. I want to set an image with transparency something like mask in the gpu image view and then I want to draw an image view over the gpu image view.
My xml looks like:

```
<gpuimageView></gpuImageView>
<imageview></imageview>
```

Because I want transparency to put image like mask on the gpu image view, I'm turning on the flag

> glSurfaceview.setZOrderOnTop(true)

Otherwise, the transparent pixels are drawn as black pixels.
But for turning on the flag, gpu image view always lies on top of other view. I've tried

> setZOrderMediaOverlay(true)

but it doesn't solve the issue of black pixels.
Can someone help me to achieve this, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I'm using TextureView instead of Surface view which is much easier to manipulate. TextureView can be used from api 14. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21572133/15497858) to solve it. Thanks!