# Can we have 720p 60fps video input using android textureView?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am using textureView for getting the video input from android camera. The problem is that if I give a 720p 60fps input, there is very significant frame drop in the output shown by camera preview. I tried both surfaceView and GLSurfaceView, they also show similar behavior. Is there any better way to acheive 60fps using camera preview or rather can we achieve 60fps using android camera?

Comment: what device are you using ? it supports 720p and/or video recording of 60fps ?

Comment: Do you capture preview frames with a callback, or you only care about display?

Comment: Hi Alex, I am catching the frames with preview callback.I put a log to measure the time between two calls to the onPreviewFrame callback and that time is highly variable (8ms to 118ms).

Comment: Hi hitman, i am using nexus4. It supports 720p 60fps but instead of the regular camera i am using a camera module which gives 720p 60fps via CSI interface.(basically it emulates the camera)

Comment: I can only quote my answer [elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19923966/192373): there are some well-known ways to screw up fast camera preview, but no recipe that guarantees it will work as fast as you want. BTW, it's possible to offload some kinds of image processing to GPU. Start with using `SurfaceTexture`.