# Android: How to delay the capture of a specific frame taken by the camera?

Tags: android, camera

I am working on a light (LED) communication system using an `Android` phone camera as the receiver that does thresholding on camera frames. For that, I use preview's callback method `onPreviewFrame`. 
To be more accurate there's a need to delay the capture of a frame every few frames so that the system will re-synchronize.

**My questions are:**

1. How do I delay the capture (not the preview) of a single frame?
2. Is it possible that there are internal changes of the camera fps rate that i'm not aware of and if so how do I limit or change them?

*To limit the camera fps rate I use `setPreviewFpsRange`, `setAutoWhiteBalanceLock` and `setAutoExposureLock`.

Comment: Please view [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19923966/2774781) to improve fps accuracy

Answer (score 0):

You can try the newer android.hardware.camera2 package added in API level 21 which replaces the deprecated Camera class and provides a fine grained control over the Camera functionality:

**Get CameraManager service**

```
CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
```

**Retrieve the camera list available on your device**

```
String[] cameraIdList = manager.getCameraIdList();
```

**Iterate through the cameraList to select a camera with desired characteristics**

```
for(String cameraId:cameraIdList)
{
    CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
}
```

**Create camera callback class with preview and still capture requests**

```
private class CameraCallback extends CameraDevice.StateCallback
{
    @Override
    public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera)
    {
        CaptureRequest previewRequest = camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW).build();

        CaptureRequest stillCaptureRequest = camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I fail to see how it help me control the ftp in real time though:/

Comment: The first part of the question is to independently control the timings of preview and capture of a single frame. By creating 2 separate requests, you can control the timing at will.

Comment: Will the `stillCaptureRequest` allow me to control the FTP? It seems it will just let me ask for a capture "sometimes in the close future". But it doesn't mean I can control the exact rate (at say 1/30 sec accuracy). Or does it?