# How to draw a tiled game board with low bitmap memory impact

Tags: android, performance

I am developing a word game similar to the most famous one.
The board has 15 x 15 tiles. There are 5 possible colors for the tiles.

The board can be zoomed in. I.e. you can either have a full view of the board, or zoom in 2X.

I have implemented 2 ways to draw the board in my Activity. Both have been tested OK on my Galaxy S and on various emulators. Both seem to work fine on a vast majority of devices. **BUT**, they both cause issues for a minority of users (which is what I am trying to solve here).

Here's for the description of the 2 designs:

### Option 1: 'big image'

**Description:**
This is the simplest one. The board is a unique `ImageView` (subclassed to handle double-tap zoom and dragging).
The image PNG resource is high res: approx. twice the size of the biggest screen size to avoid upscaling when zoomed in.

**Issues:**
OutOfMemory issues that seem to occur sometimes on big screens, especially on the 10" Asus TF101 tablet.

**Comments:**
Tests on the TF101 show that RAM usage is 3X higher than on the Galaxy S. It seems logical considering the huge scaled bitmap that has to be drawn.

### Option 2: repeat 5 small images

**Description:**
I tried to reduce the RAM used by bitmaps and to take advantage of the fact the board is just a repetition of small squares of 5 kinds.
In order to make the resizing of the board view easy, I chose to make it a custom LinearLayout, containing 15 nested LinearLayout, each containing 15 images (which is certainly not the best option performance wise).

Here's what my XML layout would look like for a 4 x 4 board:

```
        <MyCustomLinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                </ImageView>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                </ImageView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                </ImageView>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                </ImageView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </MyCustomLinearLayout>
```

**Issues:**
Some crashes or visual glitches for somes users. (I still don't have much info on this one)

**Comments:**
*Pros:* of the option is that the memory footprint is optimized: only one instance of each of the 5 small bitmaps is kept in memory. Resizing the board is straightforward: Android does all the resizing of bitmaps and nested LinearLayouts when I resize MyCustomLinearLayout.

*Cons:* Too many views, which dimensions must be recomputed by the system on each zoom.

**How can I improve Option 2 to keep a low RAM footprint, while respecting the other performance good practices (like not having hundreds of views) ?**

---

### EDIT: Final (?) implementation

Instead of a `SurfaceView`, I went for a simple custom `View`.

I was afraid that doing a lot of bitmap drawing in the `onDraw()` method would cause the dragging of the board to be laggy (because `onDraw()` is constantly called when the board is moved).

Turns out it is pretty smooth (maybe even a bit smoother than Option 2).
As for the RAM usage, it is just a bit heavier than option 2 (comparison done using Eclipse Memory Analyzer), so it is satisfactory. I still have a few reports of OutOfMemory errors ("bitmap exceeded max VM heap size"), but I think it is inevitable when one uses bitmaps.

Here is the most significant code, where I draw the 15x15 bitmaps (initialized from resources in the constructor of the view) to build the game board:

```
public void drawTileAtCoordsOnCanvas(Bitmap bm, Canvas canvas, int x, int y) {
    _rect.set(x * _sizeOfTile, y * _sizeOfTile, (x + 1) * _sizeOfTile, (y + 1) * _sizeOfTile);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bm, null, _rect, _paint);
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for (int i = 0; i < _rules.BOARD_SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < _rules.BOARD_SIZE; j++) {
            switch (_rules._boardOfMultiplicators.get(i).get(j)) {
            case NL:
                drawTileAtCoordsOnCanvas(_bitmapNormalTile, canvas, i, j);
                break;
            case DL:
                drawTileAtCoordsOnCanvas(_bitmapDlTile, canvas, i, j);
                break;
            case TL:
                drawTileAtCoordsOnCanvas(_bitmapTlTile, canvas, i, j);
                break;
            case DW:
                drawTileAtCoordsOnCanvas(_bitmapDwTile, canvas, i, j);
                break;
            case TW:
                drawTileAtCoordsOnCanvas(_bitmapTwTile, canvas, i, j);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    drawTileAtCoordsOnCanvas(_bitmapStarTile, canvas, 7, 7);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second option is the best (repeating 5 images), but instead of using ImageViews it will be way more efficient to draw directly on a custom view. The performance will be significantly better.

A [`SurfaceView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) is probably the best choice.

Comment: I think this involves drawing bitmaps on a Canvas. I thought drawing a bitmap in 2 different spots of a Canvas would result in storing the bitmap pixels twice in memory, thus causing basically the same memory usage as Option 1 ? Am I wrong ?

Comment: No, in Option 1 you have two big bitmaps in memory (the loaded PNG resource and the surface bitmap), but in Option 2 you will have the surface bitmap in memory, and the 5 small bitmaps used to draw it. This is a considerable difference on large screens.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely try this implementation and RAM-benchmark it against Option 1 and 2. Now, reading the answers there (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243433/android-difference-between-surfaceview-and-view ) makes me think I could use a View instead of a SurfaceView, as I don't plan to use neither another thread to do the drawing, nor animations. What do you think ?

Comment: In this case a custom View is probably better than a SurfaceView, because a View use less resources.

Answer (score 0):

I have no Android development experience at all, so take this with a grain of salt, but just based on looking at related questions and a bit of Googling, it seems to me that a [`GridView`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) may be what you want.

Comment: I am not too familiar with GridView, but I think it is overkill: I don't need the scrolling or the ability to dynamically add objects to the grid. Plus there would still be hundreds of ImageViews inside the GridView.