# how to edit surfaceView in layout?

Tags: android

I have the following

```
<SurfaceView 
    android:id="@+id/hero3"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5.33dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/hero2"
    />
```

inside of my layout file. 
How can I edit the property of the SurfaceView? or edit/draw images in it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't draw images in a SurfaceView from a layout file. You need to get a reference of the SurfaceView from your activity like so:

```
SurfaceView sv = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.hero3);
```

Additionally, you can't modify the SurfaceView specific properties of the SurfaceView from layouts. If you check out the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html), the only XML attributes that the SurfaceView has are the ones provided by View. You can modify the SurfaceView specific properties from code using the reference above. For example:

```
sv.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

Drawing onto a SurfaceView is a little more complex, and you should [weigh the benefits of using the SurfaceView instead of a regular View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243433/android-difference-between-surfaceview-and-view). if you decide that SurfaceView is what you need, take a look at this [tutorial on using SurfaceViews](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z2YogvILjvo)

Comment: could you give some examples?