# Making game using image views and layout (not canvas)

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have am developing a game in which most of the sprites are static (but animated). I found that using an imageview with drawable background (using xml) is giving me what I want. I may move those sprites based on user touches and have basic collision detection.

When I search the internet about the game development, most sites talk about either game engine or at least canvas/surface view. However in my case, I find deal with the normal android views and layout is enough to get me to going.

Is making a game using layout, image views and views something that is frown up? am I going on the wrong path with this?

Thanks

Comment: I think that "Keep It Simple, Stupid" is a rule of the thumb (not of the Dumb). Sometimes, "Less is More". So, keep it simple, stupid! ;) Joking, of course. No mean to be rude or offensive. If you are able to get a decent speed without recurring to the canvas, NDK or AndEngine... **Why not?**. I'm also planning a sort of "static game" where I won't even need collisions or moving the sprites (flashing is just enough for that kind of game), so...

Comment: see my answer here how simple it is to add any android.view.animation.Animation to a Canvas: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16800944/2252830

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on the kind of game you want to make. If you are making a grid based game, ImageViews could be more useful. However, almost no one makes Android games using layouts. Most people choose to use SurfaceView because it allows much more to be done, and in my opinion if you choose to learn it you will make much better games.

Of course, this is all opinion but I know nobody who creates games using the layout editor.

Comment: Well because image views have the animation capabilities and have drawable background. So why should I reinvent the wheel and start drawing using OnDraw?

Comment: Perhaps a more technical answer can be provided in this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24198359/difference-between-surfaceview-and-imageview

Comment: However, like Der Golem said, if you are simply making a static game, ImageView would work but I find that if you learn how to use the SurfaceView now, it will help you become a better developer in the future.