# Android how to draw several lines on an ImageView as another layer?

Tags: android

I would like to have the app draw several lines for showing user directions by using a background image as a base view and the app "draws" onto it in another layer on top of the background `ImageView`. Several lines would be made for the objectives to be met, and also in a specific location, so it has to have several layers too right??
I found a trick for drawing a single line using XML

```
<View 
  android:id="@+id/line"
  android:layout_width="2dip"
  android:layout_height="300dip"
  android:background="#000000"
/>
```

But that code doesn't show positions and not in a layered form.

Update :
I would like the lines to appear through drawing, not through another picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a custom `SurfaceView` class, set the image as background and paint your lines on its `Canvas`. If I correctly understood what you want to achieve, that's probably the easiest way.

`SurfaceView` is a widget from the Android framework. Extend it to make your own: `MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView`. Then override `public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)`, as android_user77 noted. Use this canvas object to paint on. Finally, add your class in the layout xml:

```
<com.your.app.MySurfaceView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/my_image" />
```

For details as why to use `SurfaceView` instead of `View`:
[Difference between SurfaceView and View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243433/android-difference-between-surfaceview-and-view)

Comment: So that SurfaceView is another Java class? And I call that class' canvas on top of my ImageView?

Comment: I have updated my explanation. This way, you do not use ImageView.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant that the app draws a static image by itself.. :(
That onDraw is for drawing by user, right?

Comment: With onDraw you can paint on top of the View,  yes. And you can use a View as a layer on top of another. What do you mean by static image?

Comment: I see, that's what I need, a view on top of a view. What I meant by static image was lines which are drawn by the app itself and the image won't change, for example if I press button "A", the lines drawn by the app are the lines started from "Start" point to point "A"

Comment: You can still achieve the end result with only 1 View, as I explained in my answer. I tested it, works for me. But if you want a View on top of a View, use a RelativeLayout. Make sure the image is the topmost View. I remember the topmost View in the hierarchy is drawn first, which is a bit counter-intuitive.

Comment: Yes I realized that it can be done by using just one view, but.. My lecturer asked me to do something a bit more complicated, so that I know what to do if I were to find another problem like this.. I need to use TouchImageView for both of the views though so they can both be zoomed in the same time.. Thanks for the help, I'm going to try it now :D

Answer (score 0):

You can extend view and do the drawing by overriding the onDraw method

Answer (score 0):

Use FrameLayout to create many "layers". I do not think you want to draw anything on the view. So do not use onDraw(), SurfaceView...

The code is like:

```
<FrameLayout ...>
<ImageView id="@+id/layer1"...> 
<ImageView id="@+id/layer2"...>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, I don't want to draw anything on the view itself, but I would like the app to make lines on top of a view, using the lines' own view.. I would like the lines to appear through drawing, not through another picture, I should update the question