# Canvas causes UI lag in simple Android game

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas

I'm building a simple Android game which does not require frame-rate speed. Think of it as a simple chess game.

I have created a custom view, where I draw the whole game using onDraw():

```
public class GameView extends View {
   public GameView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
      ...
   }
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Currently in prototyping stage, I'm just drawing lines, circles, and rectangles, but not any bitmaps.

I'm drawing each time a player makes a move using `invalidate()` (just 1 frame per player move).

The problem is that when the view is already drawn, I notice a frame-rate drop in the user interface, when for example I'm displaying a dialog or a toast to the user. It's happening when the view is already drawn, not the moment I'm drawing.

That's strange, isn't it? Since the view is already drawn, why do I notice this kind of latency in the user interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should take a look at [SurfaceView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html), which might be what you are looking for.

Views are all drawn on the same GUI thread which is also used for all user interaction.

So you should use [SurfaceView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html), which dedicates a thread to actually draw on the canvas.

I also recommend [Difference between SurfaceView and View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243433/difference-between-surfaceview-and-view)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I've read the official documentation and it's written that "If your application does not require a significant amount of processing or frame-rate speed (perhaps for a chess game, a snake game, or another slowly-animated application), then you should consider creating a custom View component". Why the official documentation suggests the custom view instead of the SurfaceView? Are there any drawbacks on using the SurfaceView?

Comment: Yea, the are a few cons against using SurfaceView.
Whilst you gain the advantages of using a different thread to draw to the canvas, you cannot gain the advantages using Hardware Acceleration. 
These are topics that have been previously debated, and I suggest for you to check it out. Please check my answer as correct please. :)

http://stackoverflow.com/a/15995353/1928275

Comment: And I suppose that OpenGL ES is best of all solutions?

Comment: Indeed it is for spacial and matrix object drawing. Simple games I'd consider using SurfaceView.